# A question of running mechanism of select statement

Tags: go

When I read the docs of select section, there are some things that I really can't understand. With the docs (and the answer on StackOverflow), select will choose one case that could run (or won't block). If there are multiple case, Go will choose one of them random.

So, in my understanding, following cases should be run by random:

```
for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 101):
            fmt.Println("time out1")
        case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 100):
            fmt.Println("time out2")
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 50)
    }
```

But actually, it always print `timed out2`

why it only print `timed out2`, I think the first case also didn't block the program, If the golang could know how many time it will cost of  the second case, how about replace this case to the operation which program can not know how many time will cost, like db operate, http request...

So I think, `select` always return that the fastest return?

Answer (score 2):

[`time.After()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) returns a channel on which a value will be sent when the timeout expires.

So you have a `select` with 2 `case`s, where both receives from channels are blocking. So `select` blocks, waits until one of them can proceed.

Your 2 timeout values are different, so the smaller one will be ready to receive from *sooner*, so that case may be chosen immediately once the timeout expires.

Your loop body ends, and the next iteration begins. You create new timeout channels, so the same thing repeats.